# Recursively Flatten list, keep track of recursion depth

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have an arbitrary list of lists and my aim is to flatten that list and also get return the level from which I have extracted each element. I should say that the simple lists contain tuples something like this:

```
[(13,1), [(12,2), (14,1)], [[(11,2), (5,7)], (8,2)]]
```

What I have already done is to flatten this list by implementing this recursive method:

```
def unpack(x):
    if x == []:
        return x
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        return unpack(x[0]) + unpack(x[1:])
    return x[:1] + unpack(x[1:])
```

This returns the following (which is quite alright for me):

```
[(13,1), (12,2), (14,1), (11,2), (5,7), (8,2)]
```

What I want to get in the end is:

```
[{(13,1):1}, {(12,2):2}, {(14,1),2}, {(11,2):3}, {(5,7):3}, {(8,2):2}]
```

So far I have tried this:

```
def unpack(x,n=0):
    if x == []:
        return {x:n}
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        return unpack(x[0],n+1) + unpack(x[1:],n+1)
    return x[:1] + unpack(x[1:],n+1)
```

But I get an error saying '`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''`

Do you have any ideas how to return the list of dictionaries ?

Comment: you cannot use a list as the key for a dict. You could try converting to to a tuple, though.

Comment: please fix your indentation. its broke.

Comment: `return {tuple(x):n}`. Or don't use a dict in the first place: `return (x,n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying the original function in the wrong way. You should transform only the unpacked item to a dict:

```
def unpack(x, n=1):
    if x == []:
        return x
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        return unpack(x[0], n + 1) + unpack(x[1:], n)
    return [{x[0]: n}] + unpack(x[1:], n)
```

so that:

```
unpack([(13,1), [(12,2), (14,1)], [[(11,2), (5,7)], (8,2)]])
```

returns:

```
[{(13, 1): 1}, {(12, 2): 2}, {(14, 1): 2}, {(11, 2): 3}, {(5, 7): 3}, {(8, 2): 2}]
```